# bash: Redirect IO , but not with suffixes

Tags: bash, io-redirection

usually I use `XX 2>error.log` , but for debug purposes ,  I prefer the following syntax:

```
function XX()
{
    redirect_io_to "error.log"
}
```

Is there such syntax available ?

It's convenient because I setup my VIM to comment / uncomment a line with some shortcut key , I could easily comment this out / uncomment it.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on how you want to use this... `command | XX` instead of `command 2>/dev/null?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but its not really pretty.

You can do `exec 2> error.log` to send `stderr` to a file

The problem is that you now have to clean it up and restore `stderr`, so at the bottom of the function you have to do `exec 2>&1`, which makes `stderr` go back to the terminal again.

```
function XX()
{
    exec 2> error.log
    foo bar
    exec 2>&1
}
```

The `exec 2>&1` doesnt hurt to leave in, so you can just comment and uncomment the first `exec`.

---

Alternatively you could make the whole function execute in a subshell so that redirections are cleaned up automatically (the parenthesis in the below example start a subshell).

```
function XX()
{ (
    exec 2> error.log
    foo bar
) }
```

---

Lastly, you could just create an alias definition that you can comment and uncomment easily, and just put it right before the function declaration.

```
alias XX='XX 2> error.log'
function XX()
{
    foo bar
}
```

Comment: exec is exactly what I want -;P

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can always stack everything you need in one block:

```
function XX() {
 (
  some
  commands
  here
 ) 2>error.log
}
```